# Node-webkit multi platform native module with nw-gyp

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-modules, node-gyp

I'm currently writing a node-webkit application which uses a native module ([`lwip`](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip)). I found out that I need to compile native modules with `nw-gyp`.
After using `nw-gyp` a new file `lwip_image.node` will be created under `node_modules/lwip/build/Release`.

1. How is the native module required? Like this: `var lwip_image = require('./node_modules/lwip/build/Release/lwip_image.node')` ??
2. If the native module was created on Win8 x64, will it also work on Win7 x64 or even Win8/7 x32? Same question for Mac vs Ubuntu x32 vs Ubuntu x64?
3. To facilitate the build process I would build the native modules on the target platforms once. After that I would like to copy them all to my project dir so I can automate the build process to build it for all platforms at once. How would I go about that? Use `os.platform()` and require depending on platform? ...

**UPDATE:** Those posts were what I was looking for: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4398#issuecomment-11233144
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your module's short name will be used in "require"
2. Your 32-bit code (compiled with target=ia32) will work on 64-bit platform, but not the other way around
3. After you have compiled your module for all platforms, it should be enough to pack different zip, .app or .exe versions for different platforms, with different respective binaries of your module.

Comment: To 3.: I would like to circumvent building the app on three different platforms. I want a solution where I only compile the native module on all target platforms once and then copy them somewhere in my project dir. I am looking for a module which requires the correct '.node' file depending on the platform. This way I can automatically build the app on my mac for all platforms using `node-webkit-builder`.

Comment: "which requires the correct '.node' file depending on the platform" - the require command is the same for all platform.  The trick is to include the correct compiled binary.  I am using sqlite3, for example, and use same command `require('sqlite3')`, but the binary in lib folder is different on different platforms.